# Error "The directory name <path> is invalid" - Windows Service with Fileshare

Tags: c#, windows-services, file-sharing

I have a Windows Service syncing files between local folder and fileshare folder. Windows Service runs on a local system. When I run it with both folders on the same computer, it works fine. But when I put fileshare folder on another computer, it throws an error "The directory name is invalid".

I have tried to reach the fileshare folder on other computer manually with shortcut, and no problems with that.

Any suggestions?

Attaching the code:

```
    private readonly string _localFolderPath = @"C:\Users\vernenat\OneDrive\Desktop\localfolder";
    private readonly string _fileSharePath = @"\\MyComputerName\fileshare";
    private readonly string _logFolderPath = @"C:\Users\vernenat\OneDrive\Desktop\logfolder";

    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _localWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _fileShareWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    private static object logFileLock = new object();
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteToLogs($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")} Service was started");

            WriteToLogs($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")} Setting up local folder watcher");

            _localWatcher.Path = _localFolderPath;
            _localWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            _localWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _localWatcher.Created += OnChangedLocal;

            WriteToLogs($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")} Setting up file share folder watcher");

            _fileShareWatcher.Path = _fileSharePath;
            _fileShareWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            _fileShareWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            SyncFilesFromLocal();
            SyncFilesFromFileshare();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLogs(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Expected Windows Service with fileshare folder on another computer to work without errors, as locally everything was fine, but got an error "The directory name  is invalid"

Comment: Where does the error throw? If it's an exception, what is the complete exception?

Comment: You should also check if your service account can access the file share.

Comment: The exception is thrown on line "_fileShareWatcher.Path = _fileSharePath;", and the message is "The directory name <path> is invalid"

Comment: Very likely locally the system the service is running on has rights to the shared folder, but when you deploy the service you are failing to configure the permissions/users.